# clojure+appengine-magic java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/IFn

Tags: google-app-engine, clojure, appengine-magic

I tried to make example to use google appengine with appengine-magic.

I think I did as the [usage](https://github.com/gcv/appengine-magic)

but I got the following problem.

```
Problem accessing /parents. Reason:

    clojure/lang/IFn
Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/IFn
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
```

this is [my source project](https://github.com/hjbaek/appengine-magic-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Clojure as a dependency in your `project.clj`:

```
[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
```

**UPDATED:**

I tried using your project and it seems to work. I needed to install appengine-magic locally (`lein install`) because it was not available on Clojars.

Comment: @ezcocoa, I was able to use your example project successfully. How are you running your app, what OS do you have and have you installed appengine-magic locally?

Comment: I have OS X and It's going well. thanks I solved this problem. installed it manually. 
1. install appengine-magic 0.5.0 and then keep the dependent libs 
2. install latest version 0.5.1 and then overwrite the libs you kept.